# Aggregate with groupby but with distinct condition on the aggregated column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have encountered a problem like that. There is a Table A, I want to aggregate it using a `group by x order by diff(which is abs(x-y)) incrementally

x and y goes always incrementally. And x with smaller value will have the priority when two different x can paired with same y

```
    x     y     diff
    1     2      1
    1     4      3
    1     6      5
    3     2      1
    3     4      1
    3     6      3
    4.5   2      3.5
    4.5   4      0.5
    4.5   6      1.5
```

The aggregate function I want is:

take the y in each group which has the smallest difference with x(smallest diff value).

BUT that y which is taken can not be reused.(for example y=2 will be taken in (x=1) group so that can not be reused in (x=3) group)

Expected result:

```
    x     y     diff
    1     2     1
    3     4     1
    4.5   4     0.5
```

seems to be very tricky in plain SQL. I am using PostgreSQL. The real data will be much
complicated and longer than this idea-shooting example

Comment: Your requirements don't define a unique result.  If the same `y` has the minimal difference from two different values of `x`, how should you determine which `x` to pair it with?  Remember that a database table may have a physical order to the rows, but it doesn't have a logical order.

Comment: So `diff` equals `abs(x-y)`? You should write it explicitly if that's the case.

Comment: What if all y values with the smallest diff have been used already, e.g. for x=3, y=2 and y=4 with diff 1 have already been used, should this return y=6?

Comment: @DavidWallace thank you for your answer. That is exactly the case I want to avoid. same y shouldn't be paired with two different x. I would say x with smaller value has the priority and column x goes always incrementally. I will updated the quesion :)

Comment: @dnoeth yeah. and if I found diff too high I can filter it with a WHERE clause. Thank you for your question :)

Comment: This is a duplicate. It's very annoying for answerers when instead of clarifying an ambigous / unclear question, you abandon them and create a new question. That's not how it's done. Please improve your previous question instead.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you for your answer. I do not think this is a exact duplicate. After realizing the question in my previous session have no chance to be answered. I do some research and narrow the question and asked from a different angel. But for sure, I will be carefull about this. Thank you again

Comment: If you realized the question could not be fixed, add a disclaimer to the question clarifying things. And a link to the new, related question to help people understand. Clean up and leave a comment to notify me and I'll reopen this question.

Answer (score 1):

If properly understood your question

```
test=# select * from A;
 x | y | diff 
---+---+------
 1 | 2 |    1
 1 | 4 |    3
 1 | 6 |    5
 3 | 2 |    1
 3 | 4 |    1
 3 | 6 |    3
 5 | 2 |    3
 5 | 4 |    1
 5 | 6 |    1
(9 rows)

test=# SELECT MIN(x) AS x, y FROM A WHERE diff = 1 GROUP BY y ORDER BY x;
 x | y 
---+---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
 5 | 6
(3 rows)

SELECT MIN(x) AS x, y, MIN(diff) FROM A WHERE diff = 1 GROUP BY y ORDER BY x;
 x | y | min 
---+---+-----
 1 | 2 |   1
 3 | 4 |   1
 5 | 6 |   1
(3 rows)
```

added `MIN(diff)` if not needed can be removed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the diff chosen is not always be 1 can be anything which is minimal in the group according to x

Comment: I hope this is what you need :)

`SELECT min(tb2.x),tb1.y,tb1.diff FROM (SELECT  y, MIN(diff) AS diff FROM A  GROUP BY y) AS tb1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM A) AS tb2 ON (tb1.y=tb2.y AND tb1.diff=tb2.diff) GROUP BY tb1.y, tb1.diff`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

t1 as table name

d as diff

```
   with cte as (
   select x, y,d from t1 where d=(select min(d) from t1) order by x )
   select t1.x, min(t1.y), min(t1.d) from t1 inner join cte on 
   t1.x=cte.x and not t1.y   in (select y from cte where cte.x<t1.x)
   group by t1.x
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it seems to be that in your code it takes diff as global minimial rather than group minimal. Maybe I should updated me example better

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment.

This problem essentially a graph problem, of finding the shortest set pairs between two discrete sets (x and  y in this case).  Technically, this is a maximum matching of a weighted bipartite graph (see [here][1]).  I don't think this problem is NP-complete.  But that still can make it hard to solve particularly in SQL.

Regardless of whether or not it is hard in the theoretical sense (NP-complete is considered "hard theoretically"), it is hard to do in SQL.  One issue is that greedy algorithms don't work.  The same "y" value might be closest to *all* the X values.  Which one to choose?  Well, the algorithm has to look further.

The only way that I can think to do this accurate in SQL is an exhaustive approach.  That is, generate all possible combinations and then check for the one that meets your conditions.  Finding all possible combinations requires generating N-factorial combinations of the X's (or Y's).  That, in turn, requires a lot of computation.  My first thought would be to use recursive CTEs for this.  However, that would only work on small problems.